# Multidimensional Array [String , UIImage] (Swift)

Tags: ios, string, image, multidimensional-array

I'm new to ios programming. I'm trying to create an array to store items I have parsed. The parse items are a String(Text), and Image(PFFile).

Im trying to figure out how I would create this array.

Would it be declared as:

```
var CompleteArray: [String:[NSData]] = []
```

////////////////////////

Okay Ive updated to struct

struct brandCollection {

```
    var brandText:[String] = [String]()
    var brandImage:[UIImage?] = [UIImage]()

}
```

Comment: It sounds like an array of structs would be better.

Comment: Ok thank you. I would be able to reference the matching image and text with the indexPath ?

Comment: Yes, your struct would have a string and NSData values.

Comment: thank you for your answer.. okay ive updated to what the potential struct should look like

Answer (score 0):

You should create a struct to hold each of your entries and then create an array of these structs -

```
struct brandItem {

    var brandText:String 
    var brandImage:UIImage

}


var completeArray: [brandItem] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'm on track based on your answer, I had came up with this:

```
struct Brands {

    var brandText:String
    var brandImage:UIImage


    init (brandText:String, brandImage:UIImage) {

        self.brandText = brandText
        self.brandImage = brandImage

    }


}

var brandDisplay:[Brands]=[]
```